# How to override a config object setting

Tags: akka, typesafe-config

I have a config file for an app that uses akka remote:

```
...
akka {
    actor {
        provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
    }
    remote {
        enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
...
```

And for another app I have a config file that includes the file with this setting. But I don't want to use akka remote in this app so I need to 'unset' it. I have tried the doing the following:

```
akka {}
```

but the previously defined akka setting still persists. Is there a way to 'unset' the previous setting in my config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just override to switch back to the `LocaLActorRefProvider`, which is the default setting for `akka.actor.provider`.  You won't need to change `akka.remote.enabled-transports` as what you have there is already the default.  So just add this config in the other project:

```
akka{
  actor {
    provider = "akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider"    
  }
}
```

Comment: That works. But I take it there isn't a more generic approach where I can just 'unset' the config value in the overriding config file?